# How to emit video in Socket.IO using Swift Client?

Tags: ios, node.js, swift, http, socket.io

Ok, so I'm having a problem...

I am developing a video chat app that sends a stream to the server by splitting up the stream into five second parts. I needed to send these efficiently and *very often*, without battery life issues, so I chose Websockets (namely Socket.IO) over long polling. So here are all the steps I tried to take, but I had issues with each...

**What I definitely want to do**

Send over a file using `NSFileManager` in a fashion without having to "decompress". By decompressing I mean...

***What I tried: Splitting into NSData***

This, of course, worked, but it is very inefficient. In any of these solutions, the data has to be taken as a `NSData` object and sent that way too. So all this is loaded into the temp storage and cached for a while. *Multiply that times 5 for group chat.* Very inefficient, and no matter how much I can "garbage collect", it results in massive issues for the app, the user, and the phone.

***What I tried: [Using Socket.IO-Stream](https://github.com/nkzawa/socket.io-stream)***

[Nope.](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-swift/issues/615) It's a JavaScript thing built for Socket.IO, but not compatible with the client. React Native, anyone?

***What I tried: HTTP Instead with Alamofire***
I actually considered this. I could bundle the data and keep the radio awake somehow. This is what you apparently do to upload file(s);

```
 let fileURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "video", withExtension: "mov")

Alamofire.upload(fileURL, to: "https://httpbin.org/post").responseJSON { response in
    debugPrint(response)
}
```

*Holy crap.* This is good, and I could load in the URL and life would be made 100 times easier. But this would be a lot of engineering to manipulate HTTP in a way that would save battery. Sockets are just made to be battery efficient to start with. *I shouldn't, and with my deadline, I can't reinvent the wheel.* I'm sure that someone out there has made a very *SWIFT (haha get it?)* way to do HTTP requests without sucking up mobile data and battery, but for now, I want WebSockets.

None of these have worked the way I necessarily wanted them to. I just need:

- Battery-efficient requests. This means not sending them often. **EDIT:** Sending them quickly together actually can help battery life, apparently. Huh.
- Memory-efficient sending. It should be in it's original, non-`NSData` form.

Am I asking for too much? Maybe. But the user is first, and I need a great app to give them. Thank you for your help in advance.

**UPDATE:** Now using a combination of RTMP to upload a stream, HLS to access it, Socket.IO to signal, and Alamofire to database. Still keeping this question open because debugging this thing was a nightmare, and I don't think sending a file and getting it back in another client requires this many dependencies.

Comment: A video chat app using http or websockets? That definitely doesn’t sound right, neither is adapted for this. Use technologies that were designed for this purpose. You might want to get a look at webRTC for instance, though there are likely many other choices. In the worst case, just use raw UDP with a very light layer to detect missing and out-of-order packets, but definitely avoid TCP. Also consider latency if you really want to buffer things, it’s going to kill interactivity completely.

Comment: webRTC to me felt like it didn't give enough control. It was kind of overcomplicated for what a video chat actually is. If anything, I'll make a custom implementation of Alamofire.

Comment: (Also webRTC isn't optimized for server, it is mostly peer to peer)